# Autocomplete for dynamic input fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I saw a bunch of topics like mine and I tested a lot but I had no luck.
On button click, the user can copy a ceartain part of a form including a autocomplete Ajax search. This part of the form is hard coded once and the search fild in works great.
But the search fild of the cloned parts doesn't work.

I tried to add a number for each colned input and call a funtion on it, but somehow it doesn't work.

**This is the Autocomplete function**

```
function autocomplete(actor_field) { 

$( actor_field ).autocomplete({

    minLenght:0,
    delay:0,

    source: function( request, response ) {
                  $.ajax({
                    url : 'path',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {search: request.term,},

                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name,
                                value: item.actor_id
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                  });
              },

messages: {
    noResults: '',
    results: function() {}
},

open: function() { 
    $("ul.ui-menu").width( $(this).innerWidth() );
}

});
}
```

**This is the cloning function**

```
$( "#add_character" ).on("click", function(event){

event.preventDefault();

actor_id++;

var newDiv = $('#character_form').clone(true);
$(newDiv).find('#voice_actor').attr('id', 'voice_actor' + actor_id);
$(newDiv).appendTo('#character');

var actor_field = '#voice_actor' + actor_id;
alert (actor_field);

autocomplete(actor_field);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your autocomplete in a jquery 'on' method so that the event will bind to new / cloned elements.

See:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it but I'm not pretty sure how to use it. It's still not working (see updated code)

Comment: You would do $('.some_container_element').on('click', '#add_character', function(e) {

Comment: I'm trying it for hours and I've read a lot more posts with solutions for my problem, but somehow nothing will work.
For more details: #characters is the Div I want to append the form. #character_form is the form that I'm cloning and #voice_actor is the input field with the autocomplete function which everytime only works on the one hard coded input field.

Comment: create a jsfiddle without the ajax

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oL7Leqr6/3/ - See working example. You needed to wrap in a container element.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, but it looks like we're not on the same thing. The click event to clone the form part worked perfectly for me. The only problem I still have is that the autocomplete function wrapped in my function actor_search() does not work on the dynamically created input fields.